# how to use the empty word in JAVACC as a token?

Tags: compiler-construction, javacc

I am setting up a parser using JavaCC and I want to use the empty word as a token (the epsilon word )

I tried to use a non terminal

```
    void Empty() : 
     {}
     {
     }
```

but i am getting an error

i tried a token 
                 < EMPTY : "" >
nothing worked

I want a token to represent an empty word

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution
I used
{ }
and it worked fine

Answer (score 2):

Do you want a token that is an empty sequence of characters or a nonterminal that matches an empty sequence of tokens?

---

As explained in [the JavaCC FAQ](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/javacc-faq-moz.htm#tth_sEc4.4), a nonterminal that matches an empty sequence of tokens would be

```
void Empty() : {}
{
     {}
}
```

[The syntax of the JavaCC grammar files](https://javacc.org/javaccgrm) does not permit `expansion_choices` to be empty.  But you can put an empty Java block as above.

However, if you have this nonterminal, then `Empty()` is the same as `{}`.  For example, I could write

```
 void SomeNonterminal() : {}
 {
     A() B() C()
 |
     Empty() 
 }
```

or I could write

```
 void SomeNonterminal() : {}
 {
     A() B() C()
 |
     {}
 }
```

It's logically the same thing.

---

A token that matches the empty sequence of characters is easy to define

```
TOKEN: { <EMPTY : ""> }
```

However, this is probably a bad idea.  If this token were to match, then it would match again on the next iteration of the lexer, and you'd have an infinite sequence of these token!

The only time this would make sense is to take the lexer out of one lexical state and into another.  E.g.

```
 <SOMESTATE> TOKEN: { <EMPTY : ""> : DEFAULT }
```

Comment: Hello @TheodoreNorvell thanks for answering in fact yes i was looking for a token that represents an epsilon (the empty word which has  a length equal to 0) but i found that it can generate an infinite sequence of those token so i get back to searching for a non terminal that represents espsilon and I have tried void Empty() : {}
{
}   and it generates an error and i cant compile it so i go back searching again and i find out that  { } works just fine  ^^